# How would I change an image matched to a specific trigger in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

I'm looking for a way to dynamically feed and image matched to a specific trigger in the URL

Example:

Url:http://domain.com?tv=panasonic

```
<img src="../images/tv/panasonic.jpg" width="275" height="367" alt=""/>
```

Url:http://domain.com?tv=sony

```
<img src="../images/tv/sony.jpg" width="275" height="367" alt=""/>
```

So someway I need to swap out panasonic.jpg with sony.jpg etc, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TV is a GET parameter, so you can do this:

```
$tv = 'default';
$chosenTv = isset($_GET['tv']) ? $_GET['tv'] : '';
if (in_array($chosenTv, ['sony', 'panasonic'])) {
    $tv = $chosenTv;
}
```

Then later:

```
<img src="../images/tv/<?php echo $tv; ?>.jpg" width="275" height="367" alt=""/>
```

Feel free to change the 'default' image to be whatever you want if TV wasn't specified in the URL.